# Output meta tag in html page header using razor

Tags: c#, razor, xhtml, umbraco

I have a razor helper that is meant to create a meta tag on the fly, however all I am seeing in the source of the page are asci characters.. the page source should read `<meta name='robots' content='noindex' />`  Much appreciate all replies and suggestions. Thank you!

Helper -

```
@helper WriteMetaRobots(DynamicNode siteRoot)
{
var robotValue = "noindex";
var robots = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(CurrentModel.GetPropertyValue("metaRobots")) ? "<meta name='robots' content='"+robotValue+"' />" : "";
    @robots
}
```

Page source -

```
&lt;meta name=&#39;robots&#39; content=noindex /&gt;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Razor encodes html to prevents xss attacks. So you'll have to explicity tell razor not to encode the html tags. Instead of `@robots` you'll want to use `@Html.Raw(robots)` here

More information about xss prevention can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cross-site-scripting)